# How to check if a comment has replies?

Tags: comments

I want a function to check if the comment id has children (replies) or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one example how to construct such a custom function:

```
/**
 * Check if a comment has children.
 *
 * @param  int $comment_id Comment ID
 * @return bool            Has comment children.
 */
function has_comment_children_wpse( $comment_id ) {
    return get_comments( [ 'parent' => $comment_id, 'count' => true ] ) > 0;
}
```

using the `get_comments()` function with the `count` attribute (to return the number of comments) and the `parent` attribute to find the children.

Comment: Could you provide a use example for this? For example,  if has children then foo, else bar etc.?

Comment: @Beaniie do you mean: `if ( has_comment_children_wpse( $comment_id ) ) { echo 'foo'; } else { echo 'bar'; }` ? Note that you need to replace the `$comment_id` with an actual comment id. You could e.g. replace `$comment_id` with an actual id (e.g. 123) of a given comment to test. If you have access to a comment object, then on could try something like `$comment->ID` or `get_comment_ID()` within a comment loop.

Comment: Could you use it as such? `if ( get_comments( [ 'parent' => $comment->ID, 'count' => true ] ) > 0 ) { echo 'foo'; } else { echo 'bar'; } `

Comment: yes I think that would work too, if `$comment` is a comment object.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl, thanks for the assist. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method in case you want to check if a comment has replies (children) within a get_comments() query. (You would likely not want to use birgire's method inside of a get_comments() query since you would be doing a get_comments() query inside of another get_comments() query.

My method is to use the WP_comment_query class's get_children() method:

```
$args = array(
'order'       => 'DESC',
'status'      => 'approve',
);

$comments = get_comments( $args );          
foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    $content = $comment->comment_content;
    $comment_children = $comment->get_children();

    if($comment_children){
        //code for comment with children
    } else {
        //code for comment without children 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$child_comments = get_comments(array(
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    'status' => 'approve',
    'parent' => $comment->comment_ID,
));
if($child_comments){}
```

Comment: That looks basically the same as bigire's query, except you're also specifying the post ID - is that needed / useful if you've got the parent comment ID? - and status = approve?